# Two Column Checkout Woocommerce

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I like to have a two column checkout on www.narwal.shop/checkout

I applied the following code:

```
/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media (min-width: 993px) {

    /* ---------------------
        WOOCOMMERCE
        --------------------- */
        body .woocommerce .col2-set .col-1{width:100%;}
        .woocommerce-billing-fields h3{margin-top:40px;}
        .woocommerce .col2-set, .woocommerce-page .col2-set{width:48%;float:left;}
        #order_review_heading, .woocommerce #order_review, .woocommerce-page #order_review{float:left;width:48%;margin-left:2%;}

}
```

They are aligned perfectly next to each other (Except the heading "Your Order" , I only want them next to each other. Help is appreciated.

Comment: With your code, you get the 2 main columns to be next to each other. What is the problem exactly?

Comment: They are now not next to each other, but underneath each other. All billing fields are still on 100% width.

Comment: But the CSS that you posted above will make them be next to each other. Your question is where to put the CSS?

Comment: Yes the code should work, only it doesnt work: www.narwal.shop/checkout do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS is setting .col-1 to be 100%. Try making it 48%:

```
body .woocommerce .col2-set .col-1 { width: 48%; }
```

and add this to .col-2 to also be 48% and to float right:

```
body .woocommerce .col2-set .col-2 { width: 48%; float: right;}
```

plus remove this whole line as that will make the containing div 48% wide too:

<del>`.woocommerce .col2-set, .woocommerce-page .col2-set{width:48%;float:right;}`</del>

Comment: Thanks Peter, I tried, but unfortunately no effect.

Comment: Have another look as I made a typo, so I've corrected it now.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if your theme has column shortcodes, that would be easier.  Here is how I accomplished the same thing with U-Design shortcodes and no CSS.

```
[one_half]
[woocommerce_cart]
[/one_half]

[one_half_last]
[woocommerce_checkout]
[/one_half_last]
```